# What is the equation of a pyramid with a square base?

Tags: euclidean-geometry, analytic-geometry

Which algebraic description can be found for a *pyramid*, defined as a scalar function $$f:\mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow  \mathbb{R}$$ 
$$(x,y)\rightarrow z$$

Particular assumptions: *Square* base $z=0 \iff x=(0,t) \lor (t,0)$
$\forall  K \ge t \ge  0 $

[image]

Comment: I guess its a region, so it has an *in*equation?

Comment: Knowing the coordinates of the base , can't we calculate its equation ? assume the region of base is not considered , i.e its hollow

Comment: For the base, you have $|x|+|y|=k$

Comment: @Tim: so we get $|x|+|y| = k(h - z)$, with $0 \le z \le h$.

Comment: @Tim but that'd be true for a square centered at origin , I am referring to a general case where pyramid could lie anywhere in space whose base is perpendicular to x-y plane

Comment: Please refer to the edit

Comment: If the pyramid is not smooth and continuous having sudden slope changes along $folds$ how can it be possible to define by  it by a single equation  using smooth coordinate systems?

Answer (score 0):

Given the center of a square pyramid of area $L^2$, $(x_c,y_c)$, and its height $z_{max}$ a mapping is given by: 
$$ z(x,y)=z_{max}(1- \frac{max(\lvert x-x_c \rvert ,\lvert y-y_c \rvert)}{L}) $$

This should be enough to *compute* the pyramid. Other operations might benefit from the formulation as an optimization problem and then re-formulation to a non linear equations system.

Comment: that was helpful , thanks :)